# AngularJS: what is $parse

Tags: javascript, parsing, angularjs-service

What function $parse() does in AngularJS? 
Documentation of [AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) has very shot and vague explanation. 
For instance,

```
context – {object} – an object against which any expressions embedded in the strings are evaluated against
```

Very unclear for me.
I comprehend that $parse() returns a function. But what this function carries? What for? And how to use result of this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJs `$parse` return a function and can be execute immediate after with `$scope`. This can be used for single variable `getter` and `setter`. eg

```
$scope.name = 'John Doh';
$parse('name')($scope);  //this will result in John Doh
$parse('name').assign($scope,'Foo Bar');
```

Angular expressions also can be used as a string argument.

Comment: Thank you. May be I have progress in my "research work". I understand what $parse does but how to use it in real situations it is closed (sealed) door still. Lol.

Answer (score 2):

In order to understand **$parse** I recommend reading up on **Angular Expressions**:

> Angular expressions are JavaScript-like code snippets that are usually
>   placed in bindings such as {{ expression }}.
>
> For example, these are valid expressions in Angular:
>
> - 1+2
> - a+b
> - user.name
> - items[index]

More: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

In short:

**$parse "returns a function which represents the compiled expression".**

Answer (score 1):

$parse is a service used by angular internally, mainly used to evaluate expression and rendering UI. This service is used as a getter/setter for single variables only.

```
$scope.text = 'abc';
$parse('text')($scope);  //this will result in abc
$parse('text').assign($scope,'xyz'); //this will set xyz in text
```